# Emails generated by contact forms

Tags: forms, 8, webforms, emails

The emails generated by contact forms I have made are full of these before the content of each field:

```
<span></span><br>
<span></span><br>
<span></span><br>
<span></span><br>
<span></span><br>
<span></span><br>
```

Any ideas why this should be? It is on every field.